# Accessibility Testing opensource options

Tags: testing

What is the best opensource tool/app that we can leverage for Accessibility testing.

Opensource tool/library to be compatible with famous IDE's like Eclipse etc.. for accessibility testing

since now the law has been passed we have to make sure our application is also accessible by chanllenged population of user who might not be able to use the site like normal population. Ours is a healthcare related project